# Sql, duplicates even using UNION

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to generate a query to return the last 4 months of summarized data, and months have to be static, I mean always display 4 rows of data:
Basically this structure:

```
month || sum(value)  
07    ||    1000
06    ||    0        
05    ||    3000
04    ||    500
```

The main table for collect the data is this:

```
trxs: {id(number), tah_fechaActualizacion(date), tah_monto(number) ,(others columns)}
```

My current query:

```
        WITH temp AS (        
          SELECT TO_CHAR (trunc(a."tah_fechaActualizacion"), 'MM') AS "formatted_month", SUM (a."tah_monto") AS "ahorrado_por_tarjeta"
          FROM "trxs" a, 
            "inst" b
          WHERE a."tah_eta_id" = 1 /*filter*/
          AND a."tah_iah_id" = b."iah_id"
          AND  b."iah_idInstrumento" = '1349153200' /*filter*/
          GROUP BY a."tah_fechaActualizacion"
         )
        SELECT temp."formatted_month", temp."ahorrado_por_tarjeta" FROM temp
        UNION
        SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(trunc(SYSDATE), -level + 1), 'MM') AS "formatted_month", TO_NUMBER(0) AS "ahorrado_por_tarjeta"
        FROM dual 
        WHERE 1 NOT IN (SELECT temp."formatted_month" FROM temp)
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4
        ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

So the problem is there will be months when you have no data records, so the first part of the query isn't enough because it doesn't return rows. I'm trying to generate dummy data with this query, but using `UNION` return duplicates, something like this:

```
07  0
06  0
06  45760
05  0
05  10000
04  0
```

Running only the "temp" part of the query, return this:

```
05  10000
06  45760
```

I don't know what is wrong with my query(duplicates using UNION), and in case this is strange, or complicated, how can you generate dummy data rows for this scenario?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the meaning of "duplicate". Duplicates are rows which are equal in all attributes and such rows will be eliminated by UNION. Your example data rows are not equal in all attributes and therefore no duplicates.

Comment: Side issue `1 NOT IN (SELECT temp."formatted_month" FROM temp)`....... in this you mean `TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(trunc(SYSDATE), -level + 1), 'MM') NOT IN (SELECT temp."formatted_month" FROM temp)` ???? , Because `1` in `WHERE` condition _DONOT_ refer the first column, but just a _numeric_ value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two choices are (1) aggregation after the union or (2) left outer join.  The following is the left outer join idea, where the months are generated and non-matching values are given a value of `0`:

```
select mons.formatted_month, coalesce(temp.ahorrado_por_tarjeta, 0)
from (SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(trunc(SYSDATE), -level + 1), 'MM') AS formatted_month
      FROM dual 
      WHERE 1 NOT IN (SELECT temp."formatted_month" FROM temp)
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4
      ORDER BY 1 DESC
     ) mons left outer join
     temp
     on mons.formatted_month = temp.formatted_month;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great using your second option =)

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` removes duplicates, yes, but for ALL fields, meaning that:

```
select 'A', 'B' from dual
union
select 'A', 'C' from dual
```

returns 2 lines, even if 1st column is the same ! So as Gordon says, you can either do a `SUM` on the `UNION`, or an outer join to take `temp` values if any, else the dummy ones.